# How to add columns in pyspark dataframe dynamically

Tags: pyspark, window-functions

I am trying to add few columns based on input variable vIssueCols

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
vIssueCols=['jobid','locid']
vQuery1 = 'vSrcData2= vSrcData'
vWindow1 = Window.partitionBy("vKey").orderBy("vOrderBy")
for x in vIssueCols:
Query1=vQuery1+'.withColumn("'+x+'_prev",F.lag(vSrcData.'+x+').over(vWindow1))'

exec(vQuery1)
```

now above query will generate vQuery1 as below, and it is working, but

```
vSrcData2= vSrcData.withColumn("jobid_prev",F.lag(vSrcData.jobid).over(vWindow1)).withColumn("locid_prev",F.lag(vSrcData.locid).over(vWindow1))
```

Cant I write a query something like

```
vSrcData2= vSrcData.withColumn(x+"_prev",F.lag(vSrcData.x).over(vWindow1))for x in vIssueCols
```

and generate the columns with the loop statement. Some blog has suggested to add a udf and call that, But instead using udf I will use above executing string method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build your query using `reduce`.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from functools import reduce

#sample data
df = sc.parallelize([[1, 200, '1234', 'asdf'],
                     [1, 50, '2345', 'qwerty'],
                     [1, 100, '4567', 'xyz'],
                     [2, 300, '123', 'prem'],
                     [2, 10, '000', 'ankur']]).\
    toDF(["vKey","vOrderBy","jobid","locid"])
df.show()

vWindow1 = Window.partitionBy("vKey").orderBy("vOrderBy")

#your existing processing
df1= df.\
    withColumn("jobid_prev",lag(df.jobid).over(vWindow1)).\
    withColumn("locid_prev",lag(df.locid).over(vWindow1))
df1.show()

#to-be processing
vIssueCols=['jobid','locid']
df2 = (reduce(
    lambda r_df, col_name: r_df.withColumn(col_name+"_prev", lag(r_df[col_name]).over(vWindow1)),
    vIssueCols,
    df
))
df2.show()
```

Sample data:

```
+----+--------+-----+------+
|vKey|vOrderBy|jobid| locid|
+----+--------+-----+------+
|   1|     200| 1234|  asdf|
|   1|      50| 2345|qwerty|
|   1|     100| 4567|   xyz|
|   2|     300|  123|  prem|
|   2|      10|  000| ankur|
+----+--------+-----+------+
```

Output:

```
+----+--------+-----+------+----------+----------+
|vKey|vOrderBy|jobid| locid|jobid_prev|locid_prev|
+----+--------+-----+------+----------+----------+
|   1|      50| 2345|qwerty|      null|      null|
|   1|     100| 4567|   xyz|      2345|    qwerty|
|   1|     200| 1234|  asdf|      4567|       xyz|
|   2|      10|  000| ankur|      null|      null|
|   2|     300|  123|  prem|       000|     ankur|
+----+--------+-----+------+----------+----------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: perfect. nice way to append columns dynamically. Thanks

Comment: Glad that it helped!

Comment: Instead of a lag function if I want to sample some values from the column can we use the same technique?

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra I guess yes. But in case you want us to have a look at your requirement then maybe you can post a separate question and share the link over here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50048027/iteratively-add-columns-in-pyspark-by-sampling-from-previous-columns My query